# How can I have different login urls for different Areas?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a .NET Core MVC site. My sites have two Areas: one for Admins, and one for front-end users.

I'm setting the Admin login url in the Startup.cs file, and this works fine:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(o =>
    {
        o.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new PathString("/Admin/Account/Login");
    });
}
```

But I need to add another one for my front-end users that just goes to "/Account/Login".

I looked all over and I don't see any way to add another Login path for a different controller or area. Does anyone know how, or if you even can, to do this?

Comment: normally applications will have single login and then based on the role,they will get redirected to different parts of the applications. Do you have different login flow,db for different areas  ?

Comment: You can refer to this url https://forums.asp.net/t/1847679.aspx?How+to+use+different+Url+for+Areas+login

Comment: why you don´t use Identity?